# System.UnsupportedException using WCF on Windows Phone 7

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

Has anyone been able to communicate using WCF on Windows Phone Series 7 emulator?

I've been trying for the past two days and it's just happening for me. I can get a normal Silverlight control to work in both Silverlight 3 and Silverlight 4, but not the phone version. Here are two versions that I've tried:

### Version 1 - Using Async Pattern

```
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/wcf/Authentication.svc");
Wcf.IAuthentication auth1 = new ChannelFactory<Wcf.IAuthentication>(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress).CreateChannel(endpointAddress);

AsyncCallback callback = (result) =>
{

    Action<string> write = (str) =>
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
        {
            //Display something
        });
    };

    try
    {
        Wcf.IAuthentication auth = result.AsyncState as Wcf.IAuthentication;
        Wcf.AuthenticationResponse response = auth.EndLogin(result);
        write(response.Success.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        write(ex.Message);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
};

auth1.BeginLogin("user0", "test0", callback, auth1);
```

This version breaks on this line:

```
Wcf.IAuthentication auth1 = new ChannelFactory<Wcf.IAuthentication>(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress).CreateChannel(endpointAddress);
```

Throwing `System.NotSupportedException`. The exception is not very descriptive and the callstack is equally not very helpful:

```
   at System.ServiceModel.DiagnosticUtility.ExceptionUtility.BuildMessage(Exception x)
   at System.ServiceModel.DiagnosticUtility.ExceptionUtility.LogException(Exception x)
   at System.ServiceModel.DiagnosticUtility.ExceptionUtility.ThrowHelperError(Exception e)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel(EndpointAddress address)
   at WindowsPhoneApplication2.MainPage.DoLogin()
   ....
```

### Version 2 - Blocking WCF call

Here is the version that doesn't use the async pattern.

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContract]
public interface IAuthentication
{
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContract]
    AuthenticationResponse Login(string user, string password);
}

public class WcfClientBase<TChannel> : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel> where TChannel : class {
        public WcfClientBase(string name, bool streaming)
            : base(GetBinding(streaming), GetEndpoint(name)) {
            ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = WcfConfig.UserName;
            ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = WcfConfig.Password;
        }
        public WcfClientBase(string name) : this(name, false) {}

        private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBinding(bool streaming) {
            System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1073741824;
            if(streaming) {
                //binding.TransferMode = System.ServiceModel.TransferMode.Streamed;
            }
            /*if(XXXURLXXX.StartsWith("https")) {
                binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
                binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
            }*/
            return binding;
        }

        private static System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress GetEndpoint(string name) {
            return new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(WcfConfig.Endpoint + name + ".svc");
        }

        protected override TChannel CreateChannel()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }


auth.Login("test0", "password0");
```

This version crashes in `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>` constructor. The call stack is a bit different:

```
   at System.Reflection.MethodInfo.get_ReturnParameter()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceReflector.HasNoDisposableParameters(MethodInfo methodInfo)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.CreateOperationDescription(ContractDescription contractDescription, MethodInfo methodInfo, MessageDirection direction, ContractReflectionInfo reflectionInfo, ContractDescription declaringContract)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.CreateOperationDescriptions(ContractDescription contractDescription, ContractReflectionInfo reflectionInfo, Type contractToGetMethodsFrom, ContractDescription declaringContract, MessageDirection direction)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.CreateContractDescription(ServiceContractAttribute contractAttr, Type contractType, Type serviceType, ContractReflectionInfo& reflectionInfo, Object serviceImplementation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.LoadContractDescriptionHelper(Type contractType, Type serviceType, Object serviceImplementation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.LoadContractDescription(Type contractType)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory1.CreateDescription()
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(Binding binding, EndpointAddress address)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory1..ctor(Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase1..ctor(Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
   at Wcf.WcfClientBase1..ctor(String name, Boolean streaming)
   at Wcf.WcfClientBase`1..ctor(String name)
   at Wcf.AuthenticationClient..ctor()
   at WindowsPhoneApplication2.MainPage.DoLogin()
   ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As scottmarlowe pointed out, the automagicly generated service refrence just works. I have set upon the mission to work out just why the bloody hell it works and the manual version doesn't.

I found the culprit and it is `ChannelFactory`. For some reason `new ChannelFactory<T>().CreateChannel()` just throws an exception. The only solution I found is to provide your own implementation of the channel. This involves:

1. Override ClientBase. (optional).
2. Override ClientBase.CreateChannel. (optional).
3. Subclass ChannelBase with a specific implementation of your WCF interface

Now, ClientBase already provides an instance of the channel factory thru `ChannelFactory` property. If you simply call `CreateChannel` off that you would get the same exception. You need to instantiate a channel that you define in step 3 from within `CreateChannel`.

This is the basic wireframe of how it all looks put together.

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public partial class AuthenticationResponse {
[DataMemberAttribute]
public bool Success {
    get; set;
}

[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContract]
public interface IAuthentication
{
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginLogin(string user, string password, AsyncCallback callback, object state);
    AuthenticationResponse EndLogin(IAsyncResult result);
}

public class AuthenticationClient : ClientBase<IAuthentication>, IAuthentication {

    public AuthenticationClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding b, EndpointAddress ea):base(b,ea)
    {
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginLogin(string user, string password, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
    {
        return base.Channel.BeginLogin(user, password, callback, asyncState);
    }

    public AuthenticationResponse EndLogin(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        return Channel.EndLogin(result: result);
    }

    protected override IAuthentication CreateChannel()
    {
        return new AuthenticationChannel(this);
    }

    private class AuthenticationChannel : ChannelBase<IAuthentication>, IAuthentication
    {
        public AuthenticationChannel(System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IAuthentication> client)
        : base(client)
        {
        }

        public System.IAsyncResult BeginLogin(string user, string password, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
        {
            object[] _args = new object[2];
            _args[0] = user;
            _args[1] = password;
            System.IAsyncResult _result = base.BeginInvoke("Login", _args, callback, asyncState);
            return _result;
        }

        public AuthenticationResponse EndLogin(System.IAsyncResult result)
        {
            object[] _args = new object[0];
            AuthenticationResponse _result = ((AuthenticationResponse)(base.EndInvoke("Login", _args, result)));
            return _result;
        }
    }
}
```

**TLDR;** If you want to use your own WCF code on WP7 you need to create your own channel class and not rely on `ChannelFactory`.

Comment: Great work. I've edited your code to add a constructor to the client so that you can specify a Binding and an EndpointAddress.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic proxy creation using ChannelFactory.CreateChannel() is not supported on Windows Phone. This is documented here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426930(VS.96).aspx

Consuming a service using the 'Add service reference' mechanism in a async pattern would be the correct way to do.

Answer (score 1):

I put a blog post together on this very subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2010/09/20/using-wcf-on-windows-phone-7-walk-through.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had any problems, but I went the "add service reference..." route which I had to do via "VS2010 Express for Windows Phone" b/c VS2010 RC doesn't yet support that feature for WP7 development. The Express version comes with the WP7 Developer's install.

Comment: Yes, that's what I found as well. I've actually almost got to the point where I can get hand crafted code to run. Will post later.