# How dynamically add WCF reference and use it in windows phone 7.5

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, wcf-client

I am building a windows phone 7.5 application and rather adding the WCF service reference by right clicking and executing the Add Service Reference, i want to generate the proxy in the code.

Can somebody help me in how I can achive this in code in WIndows Phone 7 project

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF or other .Net applications you would use the ChannelFactory to generate a proxy class at run time. Unfortunately this is not properly supported on WP7 or Silverlight.

A possible workaround is this: [System.UnsupportedException using WCF on Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474759/system-unsupportedexception-using-wcf-on-windows-phone-7)

Alternatively you could use the [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) client library to connect to the service. That may work, but it is not guaranteed. :-)

Comment: Rune,thanks for the reply, the issue is that we are building this wp7 application for our enterprise desktop application and this app will be used by our specific clients,who have different wcf addresses to integrate this app with the desktop app,if dynamic wcf reference is not possible,then it means we need to compile this app by adding references of different clients wcf addresses seperatly. Please advice.

Comment: You can create a proxy instance that points to another address than the one it was compiled with. Look at the constructors available. You should find one that takes a binding and an endpoint as arguments.